# Interactively selecting polygon in ArcMap and passing selected feature to ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, select, feature-set

I currently have a Python 2.7 script that takes a hard-coded select by attribute from ArcMap 10.3.

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("SoilLandscapePolygons_Layer", "NEW_SELECTION", "POLY_ID = 25984)
```

that then copies this polygon and its related tables into a new FGDB. What I want to do, is to have the user select a polygon and then have this polygon copied ... so that I can continue working on it in my script.  I'm not doing any editing what so ever but I need this one polygon to begin working through the various relationship tables to create a summary for the selected polygon.

Comment: Look into using a Feature Set - there a few Q&As here about them

Comment: If you have a selection in ArcMap then only that selection is used by a geoprocessing tool, you should be able to comment out the line with SelectLayerByAttribute and export only the selected polygon. This is not true for Catalog where a selection must be made within the script. Beware though, if the layer doesn't have a selection when it is passed to your script then *all polygons in the layer* will be processed, there is no Layer.HasSelection to help decide if the layer has a selection before proceeding..

Comment: Gents - I have yet to see how to set up a feature set as part of a tool or as part of an addin.  Any suggestions.  Also, I agree that once there is a selected polygon, I just can't seem to figure out how to pass it to the script.

Comment: @MichaelStimson There's `if arcpy.Describe (lyr).FIDSet:` which will return `True` or `False` depending on if there's a selection on the layer.

Comment: That's good to know @EmilBrundage. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: The fastest and simplest so far is layer.getSelectionSet (). Will return None or tuple of selected OIDs.

Comment: Is your script used from within a toolbox, or outside? If the latter, I don't think you could easily interact with the ArcMap's session, because (as far as I know), the your script and your mxd do not share the same thread and there's no way you can pass data from one place to the other. One thing you could do is using a Toolbox, or try something "exotic" like [using arpcy in a PyQT application](https://tereshenkov.wordpress.com/2017/11/26/developing-python-gui-in-arcgis-pro-with-pyqt/).

Comment: Also worth mentioning [this GeoNet accepetd answer](https://community.esri.com/thread/189531-arcpy-get-the-name-of-a-selected-features-layer#comment-663192).

Answer (score 1):

Working in the ArcMap environment you simply need to pass a string of the layer name into your copy code. Thus if the selection is manually done instead of with your `SelectLayerByAttribute_management` just skip this line of code and proceed with your `Copy Features`.

If you want to check for a selection first you can use `FIDSet`.

```
if arcpy.Describe ("SoilLandscapePolygons_Layer").FIDSet:
    ###copy features
else:
    print "no selection"
```

Comment: this is the error that I got "AttributeError: DescribeData: Method FIDSet does not exist"